# How can I select data from mySQL table from rows that are not empty?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I want to select data from my table `people` (MySQL) but only where friend is not empty:

```
$sql = "SELECT  *  FROM people WHERE friend = '$friend' ORDER BY id ASC AND WHERE friend IS NOT NULL;" ;
```

I tried to write it like this, but it is not working. In this case it is selecting nothing.

Comment: What is `$friend`?  You say you want "where friend is not empty", but then why are you searching for a value?  Also, you have your `ORDER BY` in the wrong spot.

Comment: Aside from the clause ordering syntax, by "not empty" do you mean strictly not `NULL`, or also potentially empty strings `''`?

Comment: Everything works fine when `$friend` is a name or a number, but I have the problem if `$friend` is an empty value, the system selects from my `people` table the empty row. This is what I do not want. Only if `$friend` HAS a value the system should do the operation. (I do the operation inside a for each loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL was malformed:

```
$sql = "SELECT  *  FROM people 
        WHERE friend = '$friend' AND friend != ''
        AND friend IS NOT NULL 
        ORDER BY id ASC";
```

With that said it sounds like you don't want to query at all when $friend has no value:

```
 if ($friend) {
    $sql =... etc.
 } else {
    // No query, $friend had no value
 }
```

You really want to insure your DB is as clean as possible (assuming you can at this point, and insure that you aren't inserting empty strings.

Comment: Yes perfect, this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE friend!='' ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: It is probably premature to answer while the meaning of "empty" (possibly Null) is awaiting clarification by the OP.  In any case some explanation above and beyond a line of SQL is necessary to provide a good Answer.

Comment: I use this operation in a for each loop. So it means in the case `$friend` has a value, then select from people the appropriate value. But when `$friend` is empty then do nothing. Because right now the system connects also the empty values